# Ninject ToFactory not working with parameters

Tags: error-handling, ninject, factory

I am attempting to use the ToFactory extension for Ninject, but am running into a few problems.

If I have a constructor like this:

```
public ListenerReader(IDepen1 depen1, IDepen2 depen2, UdpClient client, DataReceiveModes dataReceiveMode, int receivePort)
{
}
```

And then I create a factory to automatically create the items like this:

```
  public interface IListenerReaderFactory
  {
    ListenerReader CreateListenerReader(UdpClient client, DataReceiveModes dataReceiveMode, int receivePort);
  }
```

I receive an activation error when I try to call the injected factory:
 Error activating int
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

It seems like Ninject does not like to inject primitive types in the factories. I have also seen this same error but with the string type in another factory?

If this does not work do I have to separate the parameters into a called method?

**EDIT:**

It appears that the type in question was being injected outside of the factory. Thus Ninject was trying to create bindings for the enum and int types which failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the factory was not being called and the type was being injected directly instead.